# How can I nest $(var) variable command substitutions?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have a need to update a bash/perl script to create a file with a system process (`mktemp`),  I need to set the filename for creation, and for this I want to use the current system date:

```
LOGFILE=$(/bin/mktemp /folder/program_log.$(date +'%Y%m%d'))
```

I have since writing this found that the Bash script doesn't create any output and no file exists on the filesystem. I have only changed this line so I believe this is the cause.

result desired:

> ```
> LOGFILE = /folder/program_log.20230718
> ```

I am not very familiar with Bash. How can I achieve the intended result?

Comment: You can nest command substitutions exactly as you show. You're probably getting "too few X's in template", do you? It's irrelevant to nesting, `LOGFILE=$(/bin/mktemp /folder/program_log.$(date +'%Y%m%d').XXXXXX)` should work. `mktemp` needs a little freedom in name (those X's will be substituted by letters) in case file already exists.

Comment: @Inian just a typo. Sorry.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike my belief something is wrong is that no files are appearing in the folder and the file contents (which is dumped in an email) is always blank. I am using the date to replace the random `X` letters that where there before. I assumed my syntax was incorrect.

Comment: It appears that mktemp **requires** that there are some `XXX` in the filename to ensure no duplication. Replacing them seems to resolve this issue

Comment: Basically, the command nesting is correct, but did you check the exit code? If the template has an error, at least `mktemp` should set exit code 1. I'm actually surprised that it did not produce an error message.

Comment: @user1934428 because I was using `exec 2>"$LOGFILE"` the errors were being written to the file that wasn't created. QED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue was not the `DATE` aspect at all, but that `mktemp` **requires** some `XXXX` randomisation in the string filename to work correctly.

Using `touch` command instead resolves this issue.

```
LOGFILE=$(/bin/touch /folder/program_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M').log)
```

Comment: `touch` does not necessarily **create** the file. If a file of this name already exists, it is not truncated. In addition, the variable `LOGFILE` would not contain the name of the generated file with your approach.

Comment: @user1934428 yes of course I have bent the description to suit my situation, `touch` will create a new file or overwrite one if it already exists, but in my case an existing file with this date and time should not exist.